# SSH across all machines in network, how?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, centos, redhat

I guess this might be an elementary Linux issue, but I'm having a bit of trouble setting up a singular SSH key for a farm of machines that I'm managing.

In doing research into the matter, most of the tutorials I've seen allow you to SSH from the machine that originally generated the key into other machines in which you have placed the same key. But I would like the ability to SSH from any machine in my farm to any other machine.

Is there an easy way to do this? or am I stuck with creating key pairs between all of the machines? We are in the process of doing some scripting work, and it is vital that we have SSH access between all of the machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only is it possible, it's incredibly common!

Simply take the `id_rsa.pub` portion of the key you generated with `ssh-keygen` and install that into the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote machines.

When you SSH from your workstation into the remote systems, SSH will use the *local* private key `id_rsa` to login, which will validate against the *remote* system's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

--

You updated the question to mention that you want to SSH from any machine to any other machine.  That's not considered good security practice.  Rather, you should have a single "admin" machine that contains the private key.  However, if you must do this, copy the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` private key to all of your machines.

Comment: Thanks, I had been doing something to what you had suggested, but it turns out my problem was actually pretty simple. I had a minor pathing issue in my config file within my .ssh directory, so it was an easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could copy the same private key (`id_rsa`) to all your machines and add the same corresponding public key (`id_rsa.pub`) to all machine's `authorized_keys`.

Then you probably want to run `ssh-agent` on all machines and register the private key with `ssh-add`

However I would be a bit uneasy about this from a security point of view.

Answer (score 0):

There is even a command to do this for you, which makes sure the file permissions are correct afterwards:

```
ssh-copy-id user@machine
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ssh-agent`. You add your private key to it using `ssh-add`.

Now log into another host using `ssh -A`. This forwards your agent to the other host and allows you to log into the next host from the first one.

Given you have copied you public key (e.g. with `ssh-copy-id`) to all the host, you are therefore able to log in from any host to any other host.